# Add autoplay to a css/html slideshow, is it possible?

Tags: css, button, slideshow, autoplay

Hi I have the following css- html slideshow with controls but I would like to add the autoplay function too. Is it possible? I tried with javascript but I didn t have luck. I would like to leave the arrows and get rid of the bullets underneath.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="mySlides fade">
<img src="lara_zizektours.jpg" name="slide"  alt="" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
<img src="tremor_zizektours.jpg"  name="slide" alt="" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
<img src="femina_zizektours.jpg" name="slide" alt="" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
<img src="kingcoya_zizektours.jpg"  name="slide" alt="" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
<img src="sofia_zizektours.jpg"  name="slide" alt="" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
<img src="1_zizektours.jpg" alt=""  name="slide" style="width:100%">
</div>


<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span> 
</div>





   /* SLIDESHOW CONTAINER */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 2000px;
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
}

.mySlides {
display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
margin-top: -22px;
padding: 16px;
color: yellow;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor:pointer;
height: 13px;
width: 13px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: yellow;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your slideshow works now (you didn't post the javascript) you can set a simple `setInterval` and trigger `click()` on one of your arrow keys.

I added an ID to each of the arrows so it's easier to target in javascript. And I added a `plusSlides()` function here just to `console.log` the event triggering - you don't need that since you should already have it in your code.

```js
var next = document.getElementById('next'),
    seconds = 3;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  next.click();
}, (seconds * 1000))

/* you don't need this function - just for the demo */
function plusSlides(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<a class="prev" id="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" id="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: Dear Michael, Thanks so much for your complete answer it works perfectly now. Best regards!

Comment: Dear @VictoriaG., hi! You're very welcome. Happy to help. Great chatting with you. Talk to you again soon! Sincerely yours, Michael :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp provides an answer under the heading Automatic slideshow. You can compare with and reuse their codes and scripts.